# Comment with image attachment

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, comments, attachment

Is there a way to attach an image to a comment and display it without having to refresh the page in Jquery mobile? I haven't found a clear answer anywhere yet.

Comment: You would improve visibility to your question by adding a tag for Jquery and Jquery Mobile to your question.  The tags you're using a really generic and not very helpful.  Also, I think AJAX may be the direction you want to go with loading and attaching an image to a comment without a page refresh.

Comment: I have a fair idea of how to upload comments and display it immediately, however I'm not sure how to go about showing the image attached to the comment immediately without a page refresh.